# Best Practice - Saving Activity data to android database

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, android-database

I currently store my app data for an `Activity` in a `Parcelable` object. On orientation change, I save it and load it by using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

I want to save the data to the database when the user exits the activity.

And, I want to minimize the database calls. So,

Where should I write the code to save the data to database? Is it `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I currently store my app data for an Activity in a Parcelable object

Since the rest of your question is about database I/O, please note that `Parcelable` has nothing to do with database I/O.

> I want to save the data to the database when the user exits the activity.

I would recommend that you save the data when the data changes, rather than wait and risk losing that data (e.g., app crashes).

> Is it onPause(), onResume(), onStop() or onDestroy()?

It is not `onResume()`. That lifecycle method is called as part of activity coming onto the screen, not when the activity is leaving.

It is not `onDestroy()`, as there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called.

Either of the other two are reasonable. The primary difference is visibility:

- If an activity takes over the foreground, but that activity is themed like a dialog or otherwise allows your activity to peek through, you are only paused
- If an activity takes over the foreground, and your activity is no longer visible, you are paused and then stopped

Comment: Just to make sure, are you recommending that even if a field is changed, the whole data should be pushed to the DB every time?

Comment: @BlackCursor: Not necessarily to that degree. I do not know anything about your app and its UI construction. Your entire app could be a single activity (e.g., using fragments), or it could be lots of little activities. I try to think of "user transactions" -- what step is the user taking to say "what I did just now, make sure that gets saved", and then I map my persistence approach to that. In some cases, it's a single UI action (e.g., a delete button). In some cases, it is a collection of UI actions (e.g., filling out a form and then moving to the next activity/fragment/whatever).

Answer (score 3):

If you're really talking about best practices, then none of the above.
An Activity is View-tier object. Some might argue that it is a hybrid Controller and View. In either case, it's not a Model or Business-tier object.

If your data is important enough to write to a database, then I'm guessing that it's not view state, it's probably domain data. So, the best practice would be to let the Model/Business tier (which is completely decoupled from the Activity) handle it. And given the nature of mobile apps, I'd write to the database (asynchronously, of course) whenever the data changes, without regards to the lifecycle of the various Android components.

Answer (score 1):

A correction to the accepted answer: (I am surprised it is Mark Murphy!)

From the android documentation on activity lifecycle:

> onPause() execution is very brief and does not necessarily afford
>           enough time to perform save operations. For this reason,
>           you should not use onPause() to save application or user
>           data, make network calls, or execute database transactions;